# Sharepoint 2013: Workflow takes a long time to start

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a workflow that is automatically starting when items are modified and the value of one column is not the same as before.

The workflow is starting on the item I edit and this influences two other items. That means those two items go through the workflow as well. After they are through it this 'chain' stops.

The first workflow starts immediately, but the next two take soooo long in the state 'Starting'. There are no other workflows executing at the moment so I don't thing the server is busy or anything.

Is there a way to change that?

Thanks!

Comment: how long is soooo long in this case? what is the frequesncy of the workflow timer service?

Comment: go to one of your workflow servers and open up the workflow configuration in powershell and enter `get-wffarmstatus` and make sure everything is running.

Comment: I am not sure, maybe 6 hours.. what is the frequency of the timer service? Where can I open it?